# Hadoop Map Reduce framework for Big Data analysis

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have chosen my seminar topic on Hadoop Map reduce framework, and being a beginner I have very less knowledge about it.

My doubts are as follows :-

1. Whether the Job Tracker,Task Tracker comes as a software or Hardware?
2. As it was given in one of the examples, about map reduce been used to find occurrences of all words in some (say 3) files, then where do u give the query i.e "find occurrences of word" in map reduce program? How does map know what is to be done?

Comment: Really? Why not google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a) Whether the Job Tracker,Task Tracker comes as a software or Hardware?

Both are softwares. I.e. services running on nodes of a cluster.

> b) As it was given in one of the examples, about map reduce been used to find occurrences of all words in some (say 3) files, then where do u give the query i.e "find occurrences of word" in map reduce program? How does map know what is to be done

There is no query language, unless you are using hive. You basically implement your logic inside Mapper & Reducer classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prepare for seminar go through Hadoop Definitive Guide, starting 2 chapters.
Get to know what kind of problems hadoop solves, its architecture.
Then if you do not understand anything, happy to help :)